# Perl compatible regular expression engines: how implemented?

Tags: java, python, regex, perl, parsing

What is the basic approach used by perl, python, java and vim etc, to implement parsing with regular expressions?

Not the clever formal language approaches (i.e. `NFA`, `DFA`); nor parser combinators (e.g. [14 line regex engine](http://paste.lisp.org/display/24849)).

I've had a look at the source for java's implementation of perl style regular expressions, but its sophistcated features (e.g. back-references) and efficiency (e.g. Boyer-Moore substring matching), made it difficult to see how it *basically* works.

**EDIT**
Various sources say "backtracking" is involved (e.g. [*Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast*](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html); *formal methods* courses), but are not clear on exactly what is backtracked *on*... is it a way to evaluate an `NFA`? Can it be done from the AST of the regex directly?

What do java/perl/python regex engines actually do?

Is it something like: "a way to generate all possible words in the regular language, but abandon a specific word as soon as it doesn't match the input string".

Answer (score 7):

There are two general approaches in regular expression engines.

- Regular expressions can be transformed into finite automata. This relationship is well-studied in computer science. These finite automate can then be executed efficiently, and even run backwards. They provide strong guarantees, such as running in linear time and constant space with regards to the input string, but creating the finite automaton from the regex can be expensive. This approach also restricts the engine to real regular expressions, i.e. precludes advanced features such as back-references or recursion.
- Regular expressions can be interpreted by a backtracking engine. If an alternative in the pattern fails, this can back-track to the last decision point and try a different approach. This is extremely flexible and (with extra features like recursion + named subpatterns) can parse a much larger class of formal languages (formally, something like the LL(*) set of grammars). This is very similar to PEG parsers. The big drawback: due to the backtracking, running the regex can take exponential time – even without any extra advanced features.

On top of that, regex engines feature extra optimizations such as first searching for constant substrings in the pattern, since that is more efficient than running any kind of regex (any may even be able to use vectorized CPU instructions). If there is a choice point between multiple constant strings, those can be compiled very easily into a trie data structure (effectively, a simple finite automaton). This can reduce the amount of backtracking.

A regex that demonstrates the difference between finite automata and backtracking is the `a*a*a*a*a*b` pattern on the string `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaacb`. A finite automaton can easily see that this pattern will not match because of the `c` in the input. But a backtracking engine now has many many decision points where it can try different lengths for each `a*` subpattern. Regex engines like Perl's or the `re` module in Python go exponential in this case, i.e. take very long to complete – add more `a`s to the input to make it take longer. This allows for interesting denial of service attacks if untrusted users can supply arbitrary regexes. For untrusted input, only finite-automata based regex engines should be used, e.g. RE2 from Google.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on how backtracking works? When *automata* is discussed, they don't cover the detail. e.g. [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) and Ullman's [*Automata* course](https://youtube.com/watch?v=Tb_2HdsqypI). Do you store state (e.g. index of curr char) at every node, and for $ab$ both must match, and for $a+b$, one must match? I feel there's some tricky wrinkle where this doesn't work out... perhaps, for matching empty string? (for *optional* `?`)

Comment: @hyperpallium Your first link discusses finite automata (NFAs, DFAs) in detail, they are also featured in many “theoretical computer science 101” style courses. In each step of executing a DFA, you consume exactly one input character. Backtracking is kind of a depth-first search through all possible parses until you find one that matches the input. One way to do this is with a recursive function `search(regex_state, string_pointer)`. E.g. if the regex is an alternation of regexes `a...|b...|c...`, the search function would try each alternative until one matches.

Comment: I meant automata and backtracking as distinct approaches (as in this answer). Is backtracking really as simple as a recursive function? Is `regex_state` is the alternative we are currently in, from parent, and so recursively includes all the ancestor alternatives all the way up to root? I guess,mideally, I'd like sample code, but I don't think I've ever seen any. (BTW I'm assuming the regex is already parsed into an AST). EDIT do you mean, backtracking through the DFA? So `regex_state` is the state in the automata? Is that how java, perl, python do it?

Comment: @hyperpallium Here's a [toy regex engine using backtracking](https://gist.github.com/latk/1cd221bf38049a14a1c9064e96daa347) for you. It is geared towards simplicity and is unlike what you'd see in a production engine, where we'd save a stack of choice points instead of using recursion and wouldn't use a `cont` variable. But it shows the general concepts. Regarding backtracking through DFAs: no, you don't have to backtrack in a DFA because you're always in the correct state. You could evaluate a NFA with backtracking but that makes it difficult to detect infinite loops.

Comment: oh yeah, I meant `NFA` (not `DFA`). But if not that, what exactly do engines backtrack *on*? Thanks for your engine (did you just write it?). It looks like it uses parser combinators, and your description says `parsing with derivatives` - is this the approach used by perl/java/python etc regex engines? (BTW you've probably already come across this ["14" line engine](http://paste.lisp.org/display/24849) using parser combinators and `yield`)

Comment: @hyperpallium I updated the gist with a second variant that does explicit backtracking. That is closer to real engines, and can be mapped easily to low-level languages. Although I am copying the op_stack, whereas real engines can avoid copies by using linked lists. NFAs are typically executed by breadth-first search through the states, or by compiling them to a DFA. Parsing with derivatives is an illustrative parsing algorithm, but too inefficient for practical use. I'm using it to construct the `cont` regex. Parser combinators work well but are not used in “real” engines due to high overhead.

Comment: Thanks! First, to clarify my question: "Do java/perl/python regex engines backtrack on an NFA, an AST, or something else? What do *they* backtrack on?"

Comment: I went though your first varient, and found I could instead return `(result, string)` to backtrack to the input string state, and it works for most cases, but e.g. the `Star` in regex `a*ab` on string `ab` consumes the `a`, so the second `a` can't be matched. Yours works on this, because each repeat of `Star` is a level of recursion that can exit to the next (`cont`) part of the regex. I can't see how to do by returning tuples instead of constructing `cont`s.

Comment: @hyperpallium (1) Most engines compile the regex to interpreter opcodes, which could be an AST-like graph. Some even JIT-compile the opcodes. (2) A function `(position) → (result, position)` is a parsing function as used in parser combinators. (3) Backtracking is limited if you use “naive” recursive descent/PEG. E.g. a PEG `(aa/a)a` will match `aaa` but not `aa`, and the PEG `a*a` will never match because `a*` is *greedy* and consumes all `a`s. So PEG is an unsuitable algorithm for vanilla regexes. I don't know how mature engines avoid this problem without the high memory overhead of my demos.

Comment: Confirming 1, the other answer's source code for perl's engine describes it as a *"linear encoding of a [NFA]"* (also uses opcodes). Could one say mature engines are equivalent to backtracking an NFA, in the sense that they do exactly the same thing? The implementation details differ, but it's equivalent in visiting nodes in the same order, for the purposes of backreferences? But... you said `You could evaluate a NFA with backtracking but that makes it difficult to detect infinite loops.`, so there is some difference...

Comment: @hyperpallium Ok, it seems sensible to interpret that as backtracking over an NFA. But there are some tricky cases involving epsilon transitions in an NFA, e.g. a regex like `()*` that repeats the empty string, or nested nullable quantification like `(a*b?)+`. A breadth-first search through the NFA states deals with this elegantly, but a depth-first search combined with backtracking needs to take extra care. I don't think my demos handle this correctly either. One solution would be to break the repetition loop if the last iteration didn't advance the string position.

Comment: Thanks, I now see your demos handle empty string (multiplicative identity). I checked both your regex examples, and both loop infinitely as you thought. One (theoretical) approach detects `nullable` but IIRC it's for the whole regex. You mentioned breadth-first search before - I guess it doesn't enable back-references, which requires backtracking, I think? It's all not really as simple or elegant as it first appears. I'm actually interesting in "unambiguous" regex (not necessarily 1-unambiguous aka deterministic - e.g. $a+a$ is not OK; $ax+ay$ is), so maybe I can avoid all this.

Comment: I don't have a clear model in my mind for the search part (even for just generating all the words in the language), although I have implemented it before. It's not as simple as traversing a tree. Do you have any pointers on that? (Though it probably should be a separate question, perhaps on the computer science SE.)

Comment: By *breadth first search* of the NDA, did you mean simulating each possibility simultaneously ? [MJD's regex article](https://perl.plover.com/Regex/article.html) describes this with moving pennies on NFA nodes. Later, he describes backtracking as at each choice, just trying one; if it fails, go back to the penny waiting there. This makes it seem really simple, and I could probably code this. The code itself wouldn't be as neat as this model, but it would make sense in terms of the model. Do you think he's right? (He doesn't give the full picture til the end, at "`Lies`")

Comment: @hyperpallium I don't really have the time to go into more detail, or to read that article – but MJD is really good at this stuff so I trust the article is good. His pennies seem to correspond roughly to my backtracking points. Yes, breadth first search through the NFA states keeps track of ALL states that are possible at the current input position. Backreferences require you to keep more engine state in addition to NFA state+input position, which all has to be saved/restored for backtracking.

Comment: no need to reply just BTW I noticed BFS also has the infinite loop problem, because `()*` has a loop of epsilon transitions, giving infinite possible states.

Comment: @hyperpallium umm no, a NFA has a _finite_ amount of states. In BFS we track a set of all possible NFA states for the current input, but this can never exceed the size of the NFA. There may be infinitely many _paths_ through the NFA, but we would be tracking states and not paths.

Comment: oh, I see. You could follow all the paths, but once a state is added you don't need to add it again. If you can show the paths will never visit additional states, you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Regex in [Perl 2](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/378cc40b38293ffc7298c6a7ed3cd740ad79be52) were taken from [Henry Spencer](http://enwp.org/Henry_Spencer).

[`regexp.c`](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/378cc40b38293ffc7298c6a7ed3cd740ad79be52:/regexp.c) was only two thousand lines, it's not as difficult as later versions with more features.

Comment: You probably wanted to link [this url](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/tree/378cc40b38293ffc7298c6a7ed3cd740ad79be52) (`s/blob/tree/` in yours) ?

Comment: Thanks! That is tremendously simpler, but has extra features and efficiency, and `In some spots I've traded clarity for efficiency, so don't blame Henry for some of the lack of readability.` I could try to push through it, but I think I really need ELI5, kindergarten, pedegogically simple code.

Comment: So it seems to backtrack on an `NFA`: `essentially a linear encoding of a nondeterministic finite-state machine`

Answer (score 1):

## NFA backtracking

The various engines seem to first construct (or "compile") an NFA from the regular expression, then execute the NFA, following transitions from state to state, and backtracking to a previous state when a route fails. *Please note:* the backtracking is done on the NFA, not on the regular expression.

An **NFA** is a kind of automata, with a graph of nodes (states) connected by directed arcs (transitions). An arc is labeled with a character; when that character is seen in the text, that arc is followed. An NFA is a *Non-deterministic Finite Automata* - the "non-deterministic" part means that two arcs leaving a node can have the same label, so that both are followed simultaneously. There can also be *epsilon* transitions (ε, representing the empty string - no character), which are always followed without needing a input character.

**Backtracking** means when we come to a choice, we checkpoint the state (where we are in the automata and in the text). Then, make a choice. If it doesn't work out, we revert or "backtrack" to that checkpoint, and tnry the next choice. Like navigating a cave, when might go deeper and deeper through a series of forks before we hit a dead-end, "nesting" the checkpoints.

## Java source code analysis

#### Constructing NFA

The process for contructing an NFA from a regular expression is called "Thompson's construction". For details, please see [MJD article](https://perl.plover.com/Regex/article.html) or [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) (about 1/5 the way through, section "Converting Regular Expressions to NFAs"). There's also a wikipedia article
[Thompson's construction](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction).

Java's implementation ([`java/util/regex/Pattern.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/c46daef6edb5/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java))
recursively-descent parses the regular expression, with methods *expr()* (alternation `|`), *sequence()*, *atom()*, *closure()* (optional `?` and star `*`), generating the NFA as *Node* objects with a *next* field for the transition to another *Node*. There are many, many different *Node* subclasses.

notes: (1) *expr()* calls *sequence()* which returns with a so-called "double return" - it returns *head* explicitly, and *tail* via a global field *root*; in effect a *(head, tail)* tuple.
(2) There is no *Sequence* object; instead, the objects in a sequence have form a linked list, with their *next* fields.

#### Executing

**transitions**
The NFA is traversed with *match()* methods. The *match* method on one *Node* subclass calls *match()* method on the *next* one, so that the path through the automaton is a recursive call. The last node is a *LastNode* object, that checks that the whole of the text has been used.

**checkpointing**
The arguments of *match()* includes an index *i* into the text. It also has an implicit argument of the object it is called on. Together, this index and object represent the present state, and the *matvch()* invocation effectively checkpoints it, so we can *backtrack* to it later.

**backtracking**
The method *match* returns a *boolean*, of whether the match succeeded or not. If *true*, the returns chain all the way back to the initial call (popping off all the checkpoints, as if quickly retracing our steps back). But if *false* (due to a character not matching; or running out of text; or reaching the `LastNode` while there's still text left), backtracking occurs.

The simplest backtracking is *alternation*. The code, in *Branch.match* (line 4599 of above source) tries the first choice; if it fails, troies the second choice; and so on. If all choices fail, return *false*.

## ELI5 pedagogical implementation

Although the java implementation is may be the simplest of the engines, because least optimized, it is still very complex! There are many *PCRE* features, it handles unicode, many explicit optimizations (e.g. *Boyer-Moore* substring matching), but also many minor optimizations in the flow of the code itself, making it hard to learn from. Therefore, following is an *ELI5* simplification, using only *sequence* and *alternation*  (i.e. not even *star* or *optional*, so not actually regular expressions).

```
public class MyPattern {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ab|ac         // non-deterministic
    Node eg =
      new Branch(
        new Sequence( new Single('a'), new Single('b') ),
        new Sequence( new Single('a'), new Single('c') )
      );
    re = new Sequence(re, new LastNode());
    System.out.println( re.match(0, "ac") );
  }

  abstract static class Node {
    abstract void setNext(Node next);
    abstract boolean match(int i, String s);
  }

  static class LastNode extends Node {
    void setNext(Node next){ throw new RuntimeException("don't call me"); }
    boolean match(int i, String s) {
      return i==s.length();
    }
  }

  static class Single extends Node {
    Node next;
    char ch;
    Single(char ch) { this.ch = ch; }
    void setNext(Node next) { this.next = next; }
    boolean match(int i, String s) {
      return i<s.length()&& s.charAt(i)==ch&& next.match(i+1, s);
    }
  }

  static class Branch extends Node {
    Node left, right;
    Branch(Node l, Node r) { this.left=l; this.right=r; }
    void setNext(Node next) {
      left.setNext(next);
      right.setNext(next);
    }
    boolean match(int i, String s) {
      return left.match(i, s) || right.match(i, s);
    }
  }

  static class Sequence extends Node {
    Node left, right;
    Sequence(Node l, Node r) {
      this.left=l;
      this.right=r;
      left.setNext(right);
    }
    void setNext(Node next) { right.setNext(next); }
    boolean match(int i, String s) {
      return left.match(i, s);
    }
  }

}
```

## Proof

To be proven: the above code parses a subset of regular expressions (i.e. without *star* or *optional*). In the following "regular expression" has this restricted meaning.

First we'll prove the constructed NFA from a regular expression is equivalent; then, that the code constructs an equivalent NFA; and finally that backtracking parsing is equivalent to that.

#### Proof: regular expression to NFA

We'll begin by proving the plain regular-expression-to-NFA conversion is correct.

**define regular expression**

The standard definition of the meaning of a regular expression is in terms of the *set of words* it generates (not what it parses). This set is called a *language*, and we say *L(R)* is the language of regular expression *R*.

It's very useful to be able to express every possible regular expression in the same way (as a language), because then we can ignore the details of the actual regular expression that generated it.

- **literal `a`:** *L(`a`) -> {a}* - gives the set of that single-letter word
- **alternation:** *L(A|B) -> L(A) U L(B)* - whenever two regular expressions *A* and *B* are or-ed together, we can easily work out the language produced. Assuming we know the language of each of the expressions, both can be generated, so the resulting language is just the union of their languages.
- **sequence:** *L(AB) -> L(A) X L(B)* - the *X* means all combinations of: a word in *L(A)* followed by a word in *L(B)*.

The language of a regular expression can be built up by finding the languages of the operations forming it (following an abstract syntax tree).

**to NFA**

The NFA of regular expression *A* is notated as *N(A)*. A word generated is the sequence of characters encountered by following a path of transitions through an NFA from the start node to the exit node. Its language *L(N(A))* is the set of all such words it can generate, by following all paths.

Defining it as a language enables us to compare NFAs with regular expressions.

- **sequence:** The NFA for *AB* is constructed by putting *N(A)* and *N(B)* in sequence: the last node of *N(A)* and the first node of *N(B)* become the same node:

  ```
     N(A)     N(B)
  O------->O------->O
  ```

The possible paths through this are: from the start node (on the left), any path can be taken through *N(A)* to the middle node; then, any path can be taken through *N(B)* to the exit node on the right. This produces the same language as *L(AB) = L(A) X L(B)*

(We assume that *A* and *B* have already been done correctly i.e. *L(N(A))=L(A)* and *L(N(B))=L(A)*).

- **alternation:** The NFA for *A|B* is constructed by combining the start nodes of *N(A)* and *N(B)*, and the exit nodes of *N(A)* and *N(B)*:

  ```
    _______
   /  N(A) \
  O         >O
   \_______/
      N(B)
  ```

This combines the possible paths, just as *L(A|B) -> L(A) U L(B)*, and so the same language is produced: *L(N(A|B)) = L(A|B)*.

(Again, we assume that *A* and *B* have already been done correctly, *L(N(A))=L(A)* and *L(N(B))=L(A)*).

- **literal `a`:** The NFA for some character `a` is simply a transition from start to exit node labeled with *a*:

  ```
       a
  O-------->O
  ```

The set of words produced by all possible paths through this NFA is simply *{a}* - the set of just the one, single-letter word *a*. This is the same as for the regular expression `a`, or *L(N(a)) = {a} = L(a)*.

In summary, as we build up the NFA from the regular expression, operator by operator, the language of the NFA is the same as the regular expression at each step of the way.

#### Proof: code constructs NFA

To prove that the code above constructs the NFA, we'll first prove that that the method *setNext()* sets all the last arc out of the NFA.

**lemma: setNext() sets all exit arcs**

A *Node* object represents a node in an NFA. The *exit arcs* are all transitions to the NFA's exit node. In the code, these are represented by the *next* field referencing another node. We want to show that calling method *setNext()* will set all such exit arcs.

- **sequence:** The exit arcs of NFA *N(AB)* are the exit arcs of *N(B)* (as all arcs from *N(A)* go to *N(B)*, not to the exit node).

For a **Sequence** object (representing *N(AB)*), calling *right.setNext()* sets all its exit arcs, assuming the *setNext()* method of the component node *right* (representing *N(B)*) works correctly.

- **alternation:** The exit arcs of NFA *N(A|B)* is the union of the exit arcs of *N(A)* and *N(B)*.

For a **Branch** object (representing *N(A|B)*), calling both *left.setNext()* and *right.setNext()* sets all its exit arcs, again assuming those methods work correctly (on the *left* and *right* nodes, representing *N(A)* and *N(B)*).

- **literal `a`:** The exit arc of NFA *N(a)* is simply the one arc labeled *a*.

For a **Single** object (representing *N(a)*), setting the field *next* sets its exit arc.

Combining the above three, calling *setNode* on a *Node* object will set all exit arcs.

**Proof: code constructs NFA**

To prove this without the complication of parsing and backtracking, we won't use *match()* yet, but add a new method *gen()* that prints out the language of the NFA.

In the code, a transition from one *Node* object to another is represented by the first calling a method on the second.  The transfer of control to another *Node* object represents the transition to another node.

- **sequence:** In a **Sequence** object, the entry arcs should connect to the *left* node. This is done by the method *gen()* calling *left.gen()*.

In the constructor, the exit arcs of the *left* node are connected to the *right* node by calling *left.setNext(right)*. This is where *setNode()* calls originate, because a sequence is the only place where the concept of "following" is specified.

note: *Sequence* acts as scaffolding to assemble the NFA, and after passing control to the *left* node has no further riole.

- **alternation:** In a **Branch** object, the entry arcs are connected to both the *left* and *right* nodes, by *gen()* calls both *left.gen()* and *right.gen()*.
- **literal:** In a **Single** node, control is transitioned to the next node with *next.gen()*.

After the expression is constructed, all exit arcs are connected to a *LastNode* object by added as a sequence: *new Sequence(re, new LastNode())*.

Here are the *gen()* methods. They record the literal character encountered in the path of transitions, and are print when control reaches the *LastNode*.

```
abstract Node:
  abstract void gen(String path);
LastNode:
  void gen(String path) { System.out.println(path); }
Single:
  void gen(String path) { next.gen(path+ch); }
Branch:
  void gen(String path) { left.gen(path); right.gen(path); }
Sequence:
  void gen(String path) { left.gen(path); }
```

Thus, calling *gen("")* on a *Node* object will print out its language.

## Parsing and Backtracking

In a sense, the method *gen()* above always "backtracks" at *Branch*, because it first recurses into the *left* node, and when that returns, the state is restored: we are back to the same *Branch* object, that respresents the NFA node, and the state of the word generated is also what it was before the *left* recursion. When it recurses into the *right* node, it is as if for the first time.

The change for "backtracking" in the method *match* is simply to not continue recursing if the sought word is already generated. This does not change which words are accepted.

The change for parsing is to check the word character by character, and to abandon an avenue when a character does not match, instead of continuing all the way to the *LastNode*. One way for a character to "not match" is to not exist i.e. when the text is too short. This is the *i < s.length()* check in *Single.match()*.

Conversely, there could be too many characters in the text. This is addressed by *LastNode.match()* checking that all characters in the text have been read, with *i==s.length()*.